# Django form.is_valid giving False

Tags: python, django, django-forms

ModelsForm return datetime in ISO format like:

```
2019-04-10T06:30:00
```

In **views.py** I'm checking that character 'T' contained inside the response string and transform ISO to python datetime format. Thereafter I replace forms field with new values.
If string consist only date - *2019-04-10*, **event_form.is_valid()** return True and new instanse are creating. But if string consist time, **is_valid** return False.

views.py

```
def event(request):
    all_events = Events.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        event_form = ModelEventsForm(request.POST)
        start = (event_form['start_date'].value())
        end = (event_form['end_date'].value())
        if 'T' in start and end:#Check that time include in data string (for create events from daily and week view)
            start = datetime.strptime(start, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
            end = datetime.strptime(end, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
            event_form = ModelEventsForm(initial={'start_date': start, 'end_date': end})
        if event_form.is_valid():
            update = event_form.save(commit=False)
            update.owner = request.user.profile
            update.start_date = event_form.cleaned_data['start_date']
            update.end_date = event_form.cleaned_data['end_date']
            update.save()
        return redirect('events:event')
    else:
        event_form = ModelEventsForm()
    context = {
        "events": all_events,
        'event_form': event_form
    }
    return render(request, 'profile/event_management.html', context)
```

**form.py**

```
 <form method="POST">
              {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="event_name">Event name</label>
              {%  render_field  event_form.event_name class="form-control" id='event_name' %}

          </div>
             <div class="form-group">
             <label for="start-date">Event start</label>
              {%  render_field  event_form.start_date class="form-control datepicker" id='start-date' %}

          </div>
             <div class="form-group">
            <label for="end-date">Event end</label>
                 {%  render_field  event_form.end_date class="form-control datepicker" id='end-date' %}

          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Создать событие</button>
        </form>
```

**modelforms.py**

```
class ModelEventsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Events
        exclude = ['event_type', 'owner']
```

**models.py**

```
class Events(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    event_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

The **start** and **end** values are appropriate python datetime format

```
2019-04-09 19:00:00
```

Comment: show your form code

Comment: @c.grey the code is already in question

Comment: No, the code is *not* in the question. You need to show the definition of ModelEventsForm. And in any case, a form initialised only with `initial` data will never be valid.

Comment: Ups, sorry I added new code

Comment: When you do `form = MyForm(initial={...})` you're not binding the form (because `data` is `None`), so it will be invalid. `initial` just sets the initial values before the form gets bound.

Comment: How can I change start date_and end_date with new values in this case?

Comment: You don't. Why do you want to? The form validation will convert the string to a datetime, there is no reason to do anything to the values.

Comment: @DanielRoseman but I cant save datetime ISO format to django models. For that reasons I try to transform data and transfer their to form.

Comment: But nothing here is saving any date format. `form.cleaned_data['start_date']` has a datetime instance, not a string. Django takes care of saving that to the db in the appropriate format.

Comment: @DanielRoseman The problem is that if I leave the form field values ​​unchanged, then `is_valid () ` is always false. I can not go to the code below validation and call cleaned_data.

Comment: So please show the contents of `event_form.errors`.

Comment: I do not receive any messages , error = None

Comment: Then the form is not invalid, and you don't need to do anything.

Comment: @DanielRoseman If I stay `event_form = ModelEventsForm(initial={'start_date': start, 'end_date': end})` error are empty, but `is_valid()`== False. Then I remove `event_form = ModelEventsForm(initial={'start_date': start, 'end_date': end})` , error are `Enter the correct date and time ` for both fields - start_event and end_event.

Answer (score 0):

Did it using this code

```
def event(request):
    all_events = Events.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        event_form = ModelEventsForm(request.POST)
        start = (event_form['start_date'].value())#get datetime string from request
        end = (event_form['end_date'].value())
        #transform string to python datetime
        if 'T' in start and end:
            start = datetime.strptime(start, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
            end = datetime.strptime(end, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
        else:
            start = datetime.strptime(start, "%Y-%m-%d")
            end = datetime.strptime(end, "%Y-%m-%d")

        update_request = request.POST.copy()
        update_request.update({'start_date': start, "end_date": end})
        event_form = ModelEventsForm(update_request)
        if event_form.is_valid():
            update = event_form.save(commit=False)
            update.owner = request.user.profile
            update.start_date = event_form.cleaned_data['start_date']
            update.end_date = event_form.cleaned_data['end_date']
            update.save()                
            return redirect('events:event')
    else:
        event_form = ModelEventsForm()
    context = {
        "events": all_events,
        'event_form': event_form
    }
    return render(request, 'profile/event_management.html', context)
```